# Integration limits are large numbers and not displaying properly

Tags: subscripts

```
\int\limits_1000^2000 \frac{1}{3000}e^\frac{-x}{3000}
```

I'm using align as the maths environment in Latex so my lines of working out line up with each other.
I get the initial one in the correct subscript position, but it's not displaying the rest of it correctly. How can I fix it to show limits in the 1000s?
[image: Latex output]

Comment: you need  `_{10000}` (sub/super scrips should always be braced, if it is a single token you can sometimes omit them but not here) also `e^{\frac{..}{..}}` with braces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already pointed out in a comment, the limits of integration must each be encased in matching left and right curly braces. Separately, in order to maximize legibility, I would use `\exp` rather than `e^{...}` notation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_{1000}^{2000} \frac{1}{3000} \exp\Bigl(\frac{-x}{3000}\Bigr) \,dx
\]
\end{document}
```